# Subtracting Random Variables

Tags: probability

X and Y have the joint mass function:

$$f(x,y) = \frac{C}{(x+y+1)(x+y)(x+y-1)}$$ x, y =1,2,3...

find $V = X-Y$

if $z>=0$

$$\tag 1 P(X-Y = z) = P(X=k+z, Y=k) $$
$$\tag 2=C\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{(x+y+1)(x+y)(x+y-1)}$$
$$\tag 3 =\frac{1}{2}C \sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\left(\frac{1}{(2k +z-1)(2k+z)} - \frac{1}{(2k+z)(2k+z+1)}  \right)$$
$$\tag 4 =\frac{1}{2}C \sum_{r=1}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^{r+1}}{(r + z)(r+z+1)} $$

How do they get equation 3 from equation 2?
How do they get equation 4 from equation 3?

Comment: You can get displayed equations by enclosing them in double instead of single dollar signs. This is particularly relevant for legibility if you mix fractions and exponents.

Comment: Is what you label your "previous" equation the problem?  Where did the 1/2 come from and why isn't its denominator $(2 k+z-1) (2 k+z) (2 k+z+1)$ ?

Comment: How do they get the third line, do they factor out the (2k + z) and then apply partial fractions to the remaining two terms (2k + z - 1) and (2k + z + 1)?